# Parsing PDF file attachments

Tags: attachment, pdf, appexchange, app

I have have pdf files uploaded as attachments in Salesforce.

Is there any a way (an app on App Exchange) that would allow me to parse contents of pdf files, preferably as xml or json. The files contain only text and small logos.

I don't want to use external webservices to do this because the data is confidential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use javascript. You can use PDF.js javascript library to parse PDF and get its content.

A useful answer is there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554280/extract-text-from-pdf-in-javascript#answer-20522307

Answer (score 0):

Ive been using this solution to extract the PDF, send in via email. THen using the built in integration , it pushes to any custom object
https://docparser.com/?ref=wqlth

Comment: The question (from 2016) states not to use "external webservices to do this because the data is confidential". Do you believe your suggestion is still a good fit?

Comment: Wanted to provide an alternative solution to parse a pdf and send to a salesforce.  On this service the document availability can be set, or immediately be deleted. We had similar challenges to parse a pdf , extract text fields and send to salesforce, and this worked for me. Plus its a no code solution. It also Parses pdf and send it to our excel documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free pdf parser like https://rapidapi.com/rgtimothy/api/pdf-to-text-converter/ or host your own parser somewhere and then call it from within apex like this:

```
public static string parsePdf(Attachment file){

    String boundary = 'A_RANDOM_STRING';

    // header
    String header = '--' + boundary + '\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' + file.Name + '"\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data;'+'\nnon-svg='+True;
    String headerEncoded;
    do
    {
        header += ' ';
        headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header + '\r\n\r\n'));
    }
    while(headerEncoded.endsWith('='));

    // body
    String footer = '--' + boundary + '--';
    String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file.Body);

    if (bodyEncoded.endsWith('==')) 
    {
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0, bodyEncoded.length()-2) + '0K';
    }
    else if(bodyEncoded.endsWith('=')) 
    {
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0, bodyEncoded.length()-1) + 'N';
        footer = '\n' + footer;           
    }
    else
    {
        footer = '\r\n' + footer;
    }

    String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
    Blob bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded);

    // send
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
    req.setHeader('X-RapidAPI-Key', API_KEY);
    req.setHeader('X-RapidAPI-Host', 'pdf-to-text-converter.p.rapidapi.com');
    req.setEndpoint('https://pdf-to-text-converter.p.rapidapi.com/api/pdf-to-text/convert');

    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
    req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueof(req.getBodyAsBlob().size()));
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res;
    try{
        res = http.send(req);
    } catch(Exception e){
        system.debug('+-+ error making request: '+e.getMessage());
    }
    
    return res.getBody();
}
```